# How to fix 'error : SQLSTATE[HY000]' in migration laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Im setting up foreign key in a table. When I try run to run it I get an error.

My migration:

```php
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('camera');
    $table->integer('weight');
    $table->integer('price');
    $table->string('barcode');
    $table->date('Production_at');
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')
    ->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade')
    ->onUpdate('cascade');
});
```

The error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `phoneshop`.`#sql-1e8_70` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint `products_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)
```

Comment: What is the type of the `id` column in the `users` table? Newer versions of Laravel have changed the `increments('id')` in the `users` table migration to `bigIncrements('id')`, like you have in your migration. Try `$table->bigInteger('user_id')...`

Comment: can you share the schema of users table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have matching type on `user_id` in your `products` migrations and `users` migrations table.

by defaults, laravel `users` table use `bigIncrements` therefore you have to use `bigInteger` as your column type.